# Check if data already exist in Access table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to check if a date type exists in a table. The code I've had is this:

```vb
If CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT tbl_Fechas_Proceso_Contable.Fecha FROM tbl_Fechas_Proceso_Contable WHERE tbl_Fechas_Proceso_Contable.Fecha= " & Forms!frm_Proceso_Contable!txt_Fecha_Creacion & ";").Fields(1) > 0 Then
    MsgBox "La fecha ingresada ya ha sido consultada"
    End If
```

I've seen a similar question, but with Integer, not sure how to proceed with date type, also I don't understand why the expression `> 0`. I executed like this and Access says Item not in this collection Error 3265.

My table *tbl_Fechas_Proceso_Contable* is like this:

```
|---------------------|
| ID  | Fecha         |
|---------------------|
| 1   | 16/10/2018    |
|---------------------|
| 2   | 17/10/2018    |
|---------------------|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Date is a reserved word in Access.  Try it with brackets, and your date value in the query has to be enclosed in #'s.  Also, indexes often begin with zero, so fields(0) there.

```
If CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT tbl_Fechas_Proceso_Contable.[Fecha] FROM tbl_Fechas_Proceso_Contable WHERE tbl_Fechas_Proceso_Contable.[Fecha]=#" & Forms!frm_Proceso_Contable!txt_Fecha_Creacion & "#;").Fields(0) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "La fecha ingresada ya ha sido consultada"
End If
```

Comment: *I believe your issue was the index not existing, fields(1).  While fecha is date in Spanish, I'm thinking it's not reserved - still a good habit to use those brackets or you will encounter that issue.

Comment: But If use Fields(1) isn't that refering to the field Fecha?

Comment: If this read `SELECT tbl_Fechas_Proceso_Contable.Fecha, tbl_Fechas_Proceso_Contable.cuenta ...` then cuenta would be Fields(1).  Most indexes start with 0.  [here's a good posting on that topic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/110804/why-are-zero-based-arrays-the-norm)